# How can I load a global script (<script src="">) in Jest

Tags: jestjs

I need to make a JavaScript script available as a global script tag for a unit test in Jest.
I understand that Jest uses jsdom and in jsdom there is an api that allows to initialize the DOM and load script but I cannot seem to find a way on how to do this in Jest?

Comment: Does it need to be as a `<script>` tag? Is [this](https://medium.com/@justintulk/how-to-mock-an-external-library-in-jest-140ac7b210c2) article relevant to your case?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question, having the same problem.

Comment: For my use case, I ended up using the identity-obj-proxy as anyway has to mockup most of the api that was imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to test the script itself, which, given the fact it is an external library, you shouldn't, you can mock it globally.

First of all you need to setup a jest setupFile, this file will be executed before test execution and the mocks available there should remain available for each test file, to do so write something like this in `package.json` or, better, in `jest.config.js`

```
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/jest/globals.js"
  ]
}
```

Then create that file and write your global mocks there.

Now you will say "*'Duh'? How do I mock the external library imported through the tag script?*" Well, what I found useful for this and a number of other reason is to wrap the imported library in a separate module, this way you can use the wrapper throughout your code instead of using directly the globally imported external library, which will give you the possibility to mock the said module globally and voilà, it is done!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use require to load your script.
However, keep in mind that the script must be saved locally.

```
require('relative/path/to/your/script')
```

Some more interesting information here :
https://info343.github.io/jest.html